# sklearn.mixture.DPGMM: only one cluster?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset for which I keep getting odd results with the Dirichlet process Gaussian mixture model in sklearn.

```
import sklearn.mixture, pandas
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

A = np.random.normal(0, .5,200)
B =  np.random.normal(2, .5,200)
X = np.array(np.asmatrix(np.concatenate([A, B])).T)

dpgmm = sklearn.mixture.DPGMM( n_iter=1000, verbose=True, 
n_components=2, alpha=1, covariance_type = 'full')
dpgmm.fit(X)
print(dpgmm.means_)
print(dpgmm.weights_)
```

To plot it I am using:

```
def pdf(x, mean, var, weight):
    p = np.exp(-(x - mean) ** 2 / (2 * var)) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)
    return p * weight

def plot_gmm(model, data):
    colors = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b', 'm', 'c'])
    assignments = model.predict(data)
    clusters = np.unique(assignments)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(data[:, 0], np.zeros(data.size), c=colors[assignments], alpha=0.1)
    means = model.means_[clusters]
    variances = np.array([x.ravel() for x in np.array(model._get_covars())[clusters]])
    weights = model.weights_[clusters]
    for i in range(means.size):
        x = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.7, 100)
        y = pdf(x, means[i], variances[i], weights[i])
        ax.plot(x, y, color=colors[i], linewidth=2)
```

With DPGMM I get, across a range of values for n_components and alpha, a single component (I can't post the images because this is my first question on SO). If, on the other hand, I train a vanilla GMM with a 2 components, I get something that corresponds much better to my expectations.

```
gmm = sklearn.mixture.GMM( n_iter=1000,  n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
gmm.fit(X)
plot_gmm(gmm, X)
plt.show()
```

Is there something I am overlooking about the DPGMM?

Comment: Can you share the plots of your data, too? Maybe it only has one component?

Comment: I can't post images because this is my first post on Stack Overflow. And isn't the number of components a function of the parameter alpha, which defines the prior over the number of components (i.e. there should be some value of alpha that will result in the DPGMM finding two meaningful components?).

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960516/sklearn-mixture-dpgmm-unexpected-results might be helpful.